# Unity Auto Register ICommandHandler

Tags: c#, unity-container, cqrs

What about, I have a several classes that implement the ICommanHandler <> interface several times, as I can do with Unity to register them automatically and not one by one. Thank you.

```
public class CarCommandHandler:ICommandHandler<CreateCar>
                               ICommandHandler<DeleteCar>
{
    ......
}


public class EngineCommandHandler:ICommandHandler<CreateEngine>
                                  ICommandHandler<DeleteEngine>
{
    ......
}



public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
   container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<CreateCar>, CarCommandHandler>();

   container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<DeleteCar>, CarCommandHandler>();

   container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<CreateEngine>, EngineCommandHandler>();

   container.RegisterType<ICommandHandler<DeleteEngine>, EngineCommandHandler>(); 
}
```

Comment: Did you try `container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), CarCommandHandler, "firstRegistration"); container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), EngineCommandHandler, "secondRegistration");`?

Comment: The parameters accepted by RegisterType do not match, :0

Comment: Yes, small mistake, check it: `Did you try container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(CarCommandHandler), "firstRegistration"); container.RegisterType(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(EngineCommandHandler), "secondRegistration");`

Comment: Thanks George, but it does not help me, since it registers the generic type against the class and not all its implementations.

Comment: If you want to register all types that implement `ICommandHandler<>` you should filter all of types from `Assembly` that implement your interface and then invoke registration for all of them in a loop. I can write an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate all of types that implement `ICommandHandler<>` and register them. Code is below can do that:

```
    public static void RegisterAllImplementations(this UnityContainer container, Type openInterfaceType)
    {
        int registerCount = 0;
        // Iterate all types from current assembly
        foreach (var typeItem in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
        {
            foreach (var interaceItem in typeItem.GetInterfaces())
            {
                if (interaceItem.IsGenericType && interaceItem.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == openInterfaceType)
                {
                    container.RegisterType(interaceItem, typeItem, $"{registerCount++}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

An invocation:

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterAllImplementations(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
```

Let me know if something doesn't work